# Is it possible to do linalg.multi_dot for an ndarray along an axis?

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting, dot-product

First of all, I have a group of 12 (2x2) matrices.

```
II = np.identity(2, dtype=complex)
X = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]], dtype=complex)
Y = np.array([[0, -1j], [1j, 0]], dtype=complex)
Z = np.array([[1, 0], [0, -1]], dtype=complex)
PPP = (-II + 1j*X + 1j*Y + 1j*Z)/2
PPM = (-II + 1j*X + 1j*Y - 1j*Z)/2
PMM = (-II + 1j*X - 1j*Y - 1j*Z)/2
MMM = (-II - 1j*X - 1j*Y - 1j*Z)/2
MMP = (-II - 1j*X - 1j*Y + 1j*Z)/2
MPP = (-II - 1j*X + 1j*Y + 1j*Z)/2
PMP = (-II + 1j*X - 1j*Y + 1j*Z)/2
MPM = (-II - 1j*X + 1j*Y - 1j*Z)/2
```

Currently I have a function `operator_groups` that draws a random matrix from this group for every `j` loop and it gets appended into a list `sequence`. The random matrix drawn inbetween all the individual `j` loops are then used to do some calculations, irrelevant to our discussion here. At the end of the `j` loop, the sequences of the elements of the list `sequence` are reversed, then `linalg.multi_dot` is performed and then its hermitian conjugate is being taken (hence the `.conj().T`)

```py
def operator_groups():
    return random.choice([II, X, Y, Z, PPP, PPM, PMM, MMM, MMP, MPP, PMP, MPM])


for i in range(1, sample_size+1, 1):
    sequence = []
    for j in range(1, some_number, 1):
        noise = operator_groups()
        """some matrix calculations here"""
        sequence.append(noise)
    sequence_inverse = np.linalg.multi_dot(sequence[::-1]).conj().T
```

**Now I wish to vectorize the `i` loop**, by just doing the `j` loop in one big matrix. The `noise` is now an ndarray of N matrices(instead of just 1 matrix) randomly sampled from the group, with each matrix representing **the iterations of `j`, but parallelized.** The code now looks something like this.

```py
def operator_groups(sample_size):
    return random.sample([II, X, Y, Z], sample_size)


sequence = []
for j in range(1, some_number, 1):
    noise = operator_groups(sample_size)
    sequence.append(noise)
sequence_inverse = np.linalg.multi_dot(sequence[::-1]).conj().T
```

Now that `sequence` is a multi-dimensional array, I'm having trouble with appending the multidimensional `noise` into the right order within `sequence`, and then subsequently also problem with performing `linalg.multidot` for the inverse of `sequence` and taking its Hermitian conjugate. In this case I'd want to `multi_dot` the inverse of all the stored up `noise` for each `j` row corresponding to each of the `j` loop. **How can this be done?**

I'll provide some "pseudo-examples" below to further demonstrate my problem, using `j` = 3. For simplicity, here I'll only "randomly draw" `X, Y, Z`.

Non-vectorised case:

```
i = 1
sequence = []
    j = 1
    noise = X (randomised)
    sequence.append(noise)
    sequence = [X]
    j = 2
    noise = Y (randomised)
    sequence.append(noise)
    sequence = [X, Y]
    j = 3
    noise = Z (randomised)
    sequence.append(noise)
    sequence = [X, Y, Z]

    end of j loop
take reverse order: [Z, Y, X]
do multi_dot: [ZYX] (Note: dot products, not element-wise multiplication)
take conjugate and tranpose(to get Hermitian): [ZYX].conj().T = [ZYX.conj().T]
```

Vectorized case(say if I was doing `sample_size` = 3):

```
sequence = []
    j = 1
    noise = [X,Z,Y](randomised)
    sequence.append(noise)
    sequence = [[X,Z,Y]]
    j = 2
    noise = [Z,Y,X] (randomised)
    sequence.append(noise)
    sequence = [[X,Z,Y],
                [Z,Y,X]]
    j = 3
    noise = [Z,Z,X] (randomised)
    sequence.append(noise)
    sequence = [[X,Z,Y],
                [Z,Y,X],
                [Z,Z,X]]
    end of j loop
take reverse order: [[Z,Z,X],
                     [Z,Y,X],
                     [X,Z,Y]]
do multi_dot(along an axis,
which is what I have trouble with): [ZZX,ZYZ,XXY]
take conjugate and tranpose(to get Hermitian): 
[ZZX,ZYZ,XXY].conj().T = [ZZX.conj().T, ZYZ.conj().T, XXY.conj().T]
```

I hope these examples demonstrate my problem

Comment: I haven't read all of your question, but would like to highlight one point.  `np.linalg.multidot` does not 'vectorize' the sequence of `dots`.  It still ends up doing `dot(A, dot(B, dot(C,...)))` (actually it uses recursion).  All that's special is it can optimize the order, which only matters if some dimensions are significantly different.

Comment: Yes I understood that, but I was hoping if anyone knows a way where I could `np.linalg.multidot` for a row by row(or all the rows) at once.

Comment: Does `matmul` work for one pair of arrays?

Comment: Yes I think, but considering the `j` loop that I have to run ranges from 2 to 500, there'll be alot of `matmul` to do for 500 (2x2) matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your two random selectors:

```
In [13]: operator_groups()        # returns one (2,2) array                                                                                   
Out[13]: 
array([[-0.5+0.5j,  0.5-0.5j],
       [-0.5-0.5j, -0.5-0.5j]])
In [14]: operator_groups1(4)      # returns a list of (2,2) arrays                                                                           
Out[14]: 
[array([[0.+0.j, 1.+0.j],
        [1.+0.j, 0.+0.j]]), array([[ 0.+0.j, -0.-1.j],
        [ 0.+1.j,  0.+0.j]]), array([[ 1.+0.j,  0.+0.j],
        [ 0.+0.j, -1.+0.j]]), array([[1.+0.j, 0.+0.j],
        [0.+0.j, 1.+0.j]])]
```

Your loop creates a list of arrays:

```
In [15]: seq=[] 
    ...: for j in range(4): 
    ...:     seq.append(operator_groups()) 
    ...:                                                                                                     
In [16]: seq                                                                                                 
Out[16]: 
[array([[-0.5-0.5j, -0.5+0.5j],
        [ 0.5+0.5j, -0.5+0.5j]]), array([[1.+0.j, 0.+0.j],
        [0.+0.j, 1.+0.j]]), array([[-0.5+0.5j, -0.5-0.5j],
        [ 0.5-0.5j, -0.5-0.5j]]), array([[-0.5-0.5j,  0.5-0.5j],
        [-0.5-0.5j, -0.5+0.5j]])]
```

which can be given to `multi_dot` for sequential dotting:

```
In [17]: np.linalg.multi_dot(seq)                                                                            
Out[17]: 
array([[0.-1.j, 0.+0.j],
       [0.+0.j, 0.+1.j]])
```

If we build the sequence with the groups selector, we get a list of lists:

```
In [18]: seq=[] 
    ...: for j in range(4): 
    ...:     seq.append(operator_groups1(3)) 
    ...:                                                                                                     
In [19]: seq                                                                                                 
Out[19]: 
[[array([[ 0.+0.j, -0.-1.j],
         [ 0.+1.j,  0.+0.j]]), array([[ 1.+0.j,  0.+0.j],
         [ 0.+0.j, -1.+0.j]]), array([[0.+0.j, 1.+0.j],
         [1.+0.j, 0.+0.j]])], [array([[ 0.+0.j, -0.-1.j],
         [ 0.+1.j,  0.+0.j]]), array([[ 1.+0.j,  0.+0.j],
         [ 0.+0.j, -1.+0.j]]), array([[0.+0.j, 1.+0.j],
         [1.+0.j, 0.+0.j]])], [array([[1.+0.j, 0.+0.j],
         [0.+0.j, 1.+0.j]]), array([[ 1.+0.j,  0.+0.j],
         [ 0.+0.j, -1.+0.j]]), array([[ 0.+0.j, -0.-1.j],
         [ 0.+1.j,  0.+0.j]])], [array([[1.+0.j, 0.+0.j],
         [0.+0.j, 1.+0.j]]), array([[ 1.+0.j,  0.+0.j],
         [ 0.+0.j, -1.+0.j]]), array([[ 0.+0.j, -0.-1.j],
         [ 0.+1.j,  0.+0.j]])]]
In [20]: len(seq)                                                                                            
Out[20]: 4
In [21]: len(seq[0])                                                                                         
Out[21]: 3
```

We can 'stack' the inner lists, creating a list of (n,2,2) arrays:

```
In [22]: seq1 = [np.stack(el) for el in seq]                                                                 
In [23]: seq1                                                                                                
Out[23]: 
[array([[[ 0.+0.j, -0.-1.j],
         [ 0.+1.j,  0.+0.j]],

        [[ 1.+0.j,  0.+0.j],
         [ 0.+0.j, -1.+0.j]],

        [[ 0.+0.j,  1.+0.j],
         [ 1.+0.j,  0.+0.j]]]), array([[[ 0.+0.j, -0.-1.j],
         [ 0.+1.j,  0.+0.j]],

        [[ 1.+0.j,  0.+0.j],
         [ 0.+0.j, -1.+0.j]],

        [[ 0.+0.j,  1.+0.j],
         [ 1.+0.j,  0.+0.j]]]), array([[[ 1.+0.j,  0.+0.j],
         [ 0.+0.j,  1.+0.j]],

        [[ 1.+0.j,  0.+0.j],
         [ 0.+0.j, -1.+0.j]],

        [[ 0.+0.j, -0.-1.j],
         [ 0.+1.j,  0.+0.j]]]), array([[[ 1.+0.j,  0.+0.j],
         [ 0.+0.j,  1.+0.j]],

        [[ 1.+0.j,  0.+0.j],
         [ 0.+0.j, -1.+0.j]],

        [[ 0.+0.j, -0.-1.j],
         [ 0.+1.j,  0.+0.j]]])]
```

we can then apply `matmul` repeatedly on this list:

```
In [25]: res = seq1[0] 
    ...: for el in seq1[1:]: 
    ...:     res = res@el 
    ...:      
    ...:                                                                                                     
In [26]: res                                                                                                 
Out[26]: 
array([[[1.+0.j, 0.+0.j],
        [0.+0.j, 1.+0.j]],

       [[1.+0.j, 0.+0.j],
        [0.+0.j, 1.+0.j]],

       [[1.+0.j, 0.+0.j],
        [0.+0.j, 1.+0.j]]])
```

In effect `matmul` is like `dot`, but it treats the leading dimension(s) as a 'batch' dimension.

With random selection it's a pain to compare different results (unless I set the seed), so I leave the verification up to you.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. Any idea if this is the fastest way?Since down the line eventually I'll be doing sub 50millions operations or so